# How to cut a string after a specific string

Tags: string, unix

I have something like this:

> "10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0% packet loss"

I just need to take out "0% packet loss" how to do that?

I tried:

```
$tmp = "10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0% packet loss"
echo $tmp | sed 's/.*%//'
```

but it is giving me only "packet loss" I need "0% packet loss"

Comment: Do you mean in a shell script, with sed maybe?

Comment: By "take out" do you mean "extract and print", or "remove"? Please clearly show us the actual output you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 echo $tmp | cut -f3 -d","
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this.

First off, if you're trying to split a variable in your shell, you need to assign the variable properly.  For example:

```
tmp="10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0% packet loss"
```

Note - no `$` for assignment, and no spaces around the `=`.

Then .. options.

```
$ echo "$tmp" | awk -F',' '{print $3}'
 0% packet loss
$ echo "$tmp" | cut -d, -f3
 0% packet loss
$ echo "$tmp" | sed 's/.*, //'
0% packet loss
```

Those solutions all use pipes. While they're very portable, if you're using a POSIX shell (which you probably are), you can probably use this:

```
$ echo "${tmp##*, }"
0% packet loss
```

One more option depends on a POSIX shell AND a pipe, and splits your input in to three fields:

```
$ echo "$tmp" | while IFS=, read _ _ foo; do echo "$foo"; done
 0% packet loss
```

Or if [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) is your shell, you can do fancy things with an array (and no pipe):

```
$ IFS=',' read -r -a foo <<<"$tmp"
$ declare -p foo
declare -a foo='([0]="10 packets transmitted" [1]=" 10 packets received" [2]=" 0% packet loss")'
$ echo "${foo[2]}"
 0% packet loss
```